# Confusion regarding the container type cast on the arguments of a function when using *args

Tags: python

I have some confusion regarding what container type arguments are cast into when using *args as the input of a function. The python book I'm using for self-study states the following:

> You might also want to use the reverse process, where all given positional arguments are packed into a **list**...

This is in reference to using *args as the parameter of a function.

Once I started to play around with this, I tried the following:

```
def func(*args):
    s=0
    for a in args:
        s += a
    return s, isinstance(args,tuple)
```

This simply returns the sum of the arguments, and True, meaning the container type is not a list, but rather a tuple.

Am I missing something, or does my book have a typo?

Comment: this is a nice tutorial:  https://realpython.com/python-kwargs-and-args/

Comment: They're packaged into a `tuple`, which is essentially an immutable `list`, although strictly speaking it isn't really a list, in that `isinstance(v, list)` returns `False`.

Comment: The reference docs at https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions state: "If the form “`*identifier`” is present, it is initialized to a tuple receiving any excess positional parameters"

Comment: You're always better off referring to the official Python documentation rather than books written by third party authors, many of whom gave up on trying to learn the language and instead decided to share their lack of understanding with an unsuspecting audience through their error-riddled books.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That book has a typo. Positional arguments are packed in a tuple. You can check it with this snippet:

```
def func(*args):
    print(type(args))


func(1,2,3,4)
```

I find that two reasons might be behind this behavior. First, tuple objects are orders of magnitude (a lot) faster than list objects. This is due in part to the second reason. Second, tuple objects are inmutable, that is, they cannot be modified once they have been created.